# send data to specific url with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, url, post

i'm a newbie in codeiginiter,
i want auto send data like a form submit to a specific url,example

> http://192.165.10.X/hit/get?id=000000010101001&30001=1500:0&30002=85:2

where `(000000010101001&30001=1500:0&30002=85:2)` is a parameter i want to send.
how can i do that with codeigniter,
or can someone advice technic or share a link to be learn,
Thanks for helping me ,

Answer (score 0):

In CodeIgnitor, The URL usually will be example.com/index.php/news/article/1.
you can use `POST/GET` method to send data to any public function in the controller. In the controller function, you can get the POST data using either `$_POST` or `$this->input->post();` . If its GET method, you can use `$this->uri->segment(SEGMENT NO);`